# How to pick less than N objects randomly from K objects?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random, data-structures

From 4 objects, `1,2,3,4`. Would like to randomly pick 2 objects, but it is also allowed not to pick any, or just pick 1 object. (Considering only the combination. No order.)

So the possible states are the following 11 states:

```
[(empty)],[1],[2],[3],[4],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]
```

How to generate one of the states above at the possibility of once in 11 times?

Need to write generalized version of this. Pick less than N objects randomly from K objects.

Comment: One way is to generate above mentioned possibilities and then randomly select one.

Comment: Yes, but if you have big K, it would not be possible.

Comment: You could first choose the number of elements to pick with probabilities 1:4:6 in the example, then randomly pick this number of elements.

Comment: Should you provide equal probablilities for all cases?

Comment: @Shu: What are the expected values of N and K?

Comment: @Mbo yes. It should be equally random.

Comment: @rici It is like N=13, K=52. (I'm writing this for playing cards). Combination(52,13) gives you 635013559600 patterns.

Comment: @shu: yeah, in that case you can precompute the discrete distribution weights and get the result quickly. There's a faster solution if k is at least n/2 (or maybe  a little smaller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to determine how many objects you want to pick. In your example you have 11 possible subsets, 1 of size 0, 4 of size 1, and 6 of size 2. You should therefore pick a size 0, 1, or 2 according to the weighted distribution 1:4:6. One way to visualize this is to imagine 11 equally sized, equally spaced slots: 1 labelled with 0, 4 labelled with 1, and 6 labelled with 2. Now, drop a ball randomly into one of the slots, and note the label. Each slot has an equal probability of receiving a ball, but the probability of getting a slot with label 0, 1, or 2 is in the proportion 1:4:6.

In general the number of combinations of `k` objects from a set of size `n` is given by `n!/(k!*(n-k)!)`. We can use this formula to determine our weighted distribution. Note that I'm following the normal convention of using `k` to represent the number of objects being picked, from `n` possibilities - you use them in the opposite sense, which is a little confusing.

Once you've determined the number of picks `p`, you randomly select `p` elements from the input, using something like the Durstenfeld variation of the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static <E> List<E> randomPick(List<E> in, int k)
{   
    int n = in.size();

    // determine number of elements to pick using a random selection
    // weighted by the number of subsets of each size, 0..k
    Random r = new Random();
    NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=k; i++)
    {
        total += fact(n)/(fact(i)*fact(n-i));
        map.put(total, i);
    }       
    int p = map.higherEntry(r.nextInt(total)).getValue();

    // Use Durstenfeld shuffle to pick p random elements from list
    List<E> out = new ArrayList<>(in);
    for(int i=n-1; i>=n-p; i--)
    {
        Collections.swap(out, i , r.nextInt(i + 1));
    }       
    return out.subList(n-p, n);
}

static int fact(int n)
{
    int f = 1;
    while(n > 0) f *= n--;
    return f;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Integer> in = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);       
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        System.out.println(randomPick(in, 2));
}
```

Output:

```
[]
[2, 1]
[4]
[3, 2]
[1]
[1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 3]
[4]
[1, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well for me. As I wrote this in C++, I used discrete_distribution generator for NavigableMap part.